# Why do you need a IOS Developer Certificate to run IOS app on Device?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

A bit of a beginner to IOS. I am trying to understand Certificates, Provisioning Profiles, Code Signing Identities and frankly, it is a bit difficult for me to understand the developer docs.

I understand that the Certificate is a security mechanism for Apple to ensure that no one has tampered with your code, with a Public and Private Key (for you to sign off on your application). This makes sense when you submit your app to the app store or for adhoc testing, as Apple wants to make sure this is the final version that you would like to submit (IOS Distribution Certificate). But how does that apply for IOS Developer Certificate?

From what I understand, IOS Developer Certificate is used to limit who can run your application and on what devices it can be run on.

Answer (score 1):

Development certificate is mostly used while application is being developed and it limits number of number devices (100) on which app can be installed. Also distribution certificate won't let you debug the application while installing from Xcode and disconnect you. It is primarily for signing app store build. There's no difference in the certificates themselves other than the separation Apple does for you.

> Code signing your app assures users that it is from a known source and the app hasn’t been modified since it was last signed.

You can refer [Code Signing](https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/inside-code-signing/), if describes how code signing works in detail. It will help you understand why code signing is required.